# Get raw data from a section in a PE file

Tags: portable-executable

I'm writting a PE viewer. I'm trying to print raw data of each section.

I want to use `section[i]->PointerToRawData` in order to jump to section and create a loop with `section[i]->SizeOfRawData)` to print raw data

Can you show me a flow to do that and how I display raw data?

Thank you and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PointerToRawData is an offset relative to the beginning of the file, so simply adding it to the memory address you have loaded the file should give you the starting point.  It sounds like you might want to try something like this:

```
const BYTE* p = (BYTE*)pFileBase + section[i]->PointerToRawData;
const BYTE* pEnd = p + section[i]->SizeOfRawData;
while (p<pEnd)
{
    your_char_output_routine_goes_here(*p++);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how to get hex value of these data? And when I print these data, they have null character. How to handle that?

Comment: Displaying a hex byte value, you'd use something like printf("%02X",*p); the character column of hex dump conventionally displays a period for ASCII codes below 32 and above 126, otherwise you can display the character directly. E.g.: printf("%c",(*p<32 || *p>126)?'.':*p);